# Binding Text of TextBox to sum of list<T> value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I've a question. I have a class:

```
public class ParagonClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //some variables
    private decimal _totalValue;

    public static ObservableCollection<ParagonClass> paragonLista { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (ProductID > 0)
                _totalValue = Math.Round(ProductCount * PriceBrutto, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
            return _totalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _totalValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

In my window I'd like to bind sum of TotalValue (of all paragonLista elements) to Text of TextBox. I tried few options but with no effect. Best what I get was calculate what I want but only when I opening old, name it document. When I add new position to this document, the value in TextBox doesn't change. I achieved that with:

```
 private decimal _Sum;
 public decimal Sum
 {
     get
     {
         _Sum = ParagonClass.paragonLista.Sum(x => x.TotalValue);
         return _Sum;
     }
 }
```

and in .xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="priceTextBox" FontSize="28" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Sum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Where are you raising the event to notify the `Sum` has changes, aka `NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");`?

Comment: Do you really want the setter on your `TotalValue` property, if your getter is returning a value calculated from other data?

Comment: @Mashton I added wrong code, the setter isn't there.

Comment: @rae1n I don't raise the event, because ObservableCollection changing in few windows (but TotalValue from ParagonClass is still the correct value for each element)

Comment: Yes, but you need to raise the event to notify the view that it needs to refresh the `Sum` value. The event needs to be risen from any operation that might affect the `Sum`.

Comment: Are you ever setting the `TotalValue` property? ex. `paragonInstance.TotalValue = 5.0;` It will never update if you try and set the value via. the backing field.

Comment: @KevinDeLorey I checked and TotalValue changing when I'm doing i.e.:
ParagonClass pc = new ParagonClass();
pc.ProductCount = 1;
pc.PriceBrutto = 10;
here TotalValue = 10;
after:
pc.ProductCount = 2;
the TotalValue is 20.

Comment: @rae1n Like I answered Sheridan (both of you telling the same thing) - I'll check it tomorrow at work. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mixing everything together you need two classes.

```
public class ParagonClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  //some variables
  private decimal _totalValue;

  public decimal TotalValue
  {
    get
    {
        if (ProductID > 0)
            _totalValue = Math.Round(ProductCount * PriceBrutto, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        return _totalValue;
    }
  // No need for a setter if its calculated
  // See Sheridan's answer for how to do this
  //       set
  //       {
  //           _totalValue = value;
  //           NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
  //       }
  }

  ...
}
```

And a collection

```
public class ParagonCollection : ObservableCollection<ParagonClass>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int sum;
  public int Sum
  { 
    get{ return sum;} 
    set
    {
      sum = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");
    }
 }
  // You'll need as implantation of INotifyPropertyChanged here
  // and some extra stuff to come
  ...
}
```

Now we just need to calculate the sum whenever the it changes. There are several times this occurs

1. When a new Paragon is added to the collection
2. When a Paragon changes

Lets take them one at a time, and we can hook up the Paragon items being added via the collection by listening for collection changes in the constructor

```
public ParagonCollection()
{
   // When the collection changes set the Sum to the new Sum of TotalValues
   this.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
{
  Recalculate();
}

private void Recalculate()
{
  Sum = this.Sum(x=>x.TotalValue);
}
```

Now if you design your `ParagonClass` so that the items are immutable (i.e they don't change after they have been created), then you should be all done. However if you need your Paragons to change we need to rewrite what happens when we add or remove an item

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
  foreach(ParagonClass item in args.OldItems)
  {
    // Unsubscribe to changes in each item
    item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemChanged;
  }
  foreach(ParagonClass item in args.NewItems)
  {
    // Subscribe to future changes for each item
    item.PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
  }

  Recalculate();
}

private void OnItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  Recalulate();

  // You might decide that you only want to recalculate for some property 
  // changes, and do something like the following instead
  // if (args.PropertyName=="TotalValue")
  //   Recalulate();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In a normal property `setter` in WPF, you would call `NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` to alert the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to the fact that the `PropertyName` property has been changed and that you want to see the changes in the UI.

In cases like yours, where you have no property `setter`, you *still* need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName")` to see the changes in the UI. Now clearly, you can't call it from the `setter` as it doesn't have one.

It is most usual to call it from another property `setter` that plays a part in the output value of the property without the `setter`. For example, a `FirstName` property might be used in an `Initials` property without a `setter`:

```
public string Initial
{
    get { return FirstName[0].ToString(); }
}
```

Now this property will only change when the `FirstName` property changes, so the sensible place to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Initial")` would be in *that* property:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        _firstName= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Initial");

    }
}
```

You don't have to call it in any property though... you could also call it wherever you change the associated values:

```
FirstName = SomeObject.GetFirstName(someIdNumber);
NotifyPropertyChanged("Initial");
```

So, wherever you call it from, you still need to call the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update TotalValue when the "ProductCount" or "PriceBertto" change, you will need to notify WPF of that change. You could try something like this:

```
...
public double TotalValue
{
    get
    {
         return Math.Round (ProductCount * PriceBrutto, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero );
    }
}

private int productCount = 0;
public int ProductCount
{
    get
    {
        return productCount;
    }
    set
    {
        if( Equals( productCount, value) ) return;
        productCount = value;

        NotifyPropertyChange( "ProductCount" );
        NotifyPropertyChange( "TotalValue" );
    }
 }

...
```

Notice that NotifyPropertyChange for "TotalValue" is invoked from the setter of ProductCount.

I didn't do it all for you, but you can do similar things for your other properties as well. can do the similar things for your other properties that affect TotalValue.

Comment: It looks like @Sheridan beat me, and I didn't see his answer, but I'll leave it up as another example for you.